# Android: ListView hiding layout below when too many items

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have this FileBrowser layout. When the linked view opens, I fill the ListView programmatically. The problem is: When there is too much items in the listview, that is, when there is enough items for a scroll bar to appear, the LinearLayout below containing the two buttons disappears.

Not to much items. The LinearLayout containing the two buttons is there as it should:
[image]

Too much items. I scrolled to the bottom and the LinearLayout containing the two buttons isn't there:
[image]

My layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/baseContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCurrentPath"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeL"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="/current/path/"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/filesListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
            style="@style/RexforetTheme.Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_retour"
            android:text="@string/btn_cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/selectBtn"
            style="@style/RexforetTheme.Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_check"
            android:text="@string/btn_select" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `ListView` xml to the following

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/filesListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</ListView>
```

The change of `android:layout_height` to `0dp` and the addition of `android:layout_weight="1"` will allow the `ListView` to grow to use the rest of the available space in your layout.

This means that your two buttons will always be visible, and positioned at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Ah! I see. It works, and thanks for explaining how/why it works. I'll be back in 10 minutes to mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

divide it according to weight something like this
it should work

```
<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/baseContainer"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:padding="10dp"
     android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:weight="4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCurrentPath"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeL"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="/current/path/"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/filesListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
        style="@style/RexforetTheme.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_retour"
        android:text="@string/btn_cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/selectBtn"
        style="@style/RexforetTheme.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_check"
        android:text="@string/btn_select" />
</LinearLayout>
```